# SQLite issues, escaping certain characters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I'm working on my first database application. It is a WinForms application written in C# using a SQLite database.

I've come across some problems, when a apostrophe is used, my SQLite query fails. Here is the structure of my queries.

```
string SQL = "UPDATE SUBCONTRACTOR SET JobSite = NULL WHERE JobSite = '" + jobSite + "'";
```

For instance, if an apostrophe is used in the jobSite var, it offsets the other apostrophes in the command, and fails.

So my questions are:

**1. How do I escape characters like the apostrophe and semicolon in the above query example?**

**2. What characters do I need to escape? I know I should escape the apostrophe, what else is dangerous?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd really like to avoid asking another question, an addition to my questions above, can someone show me how to build a query like the one I have above using parameters with the UPDATE/WHERE command? I've seen lots of examples of queries using parameters, but they always use the INSERT command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather use Parameters

There is a previous stack-overflow question about it

[Adding parameters in SQLite with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c)

if you need more functionality you can also use Entity Framework

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Sorry not to familiar with the Syntax but the concept should same.
Something like :

```
SQLiteCommand Command = "UPDATE SUBCONTRACTOR SET JobSite = NULL WHERE JobSite = @JobSite";
Command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@JobSite", JobSiteVariable));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks! But, how do I modify my UPDATE/WHERE query to use parameters? I see plenty of examples of using parameters, but they always use INSERT.

Answer (score 3):

to escape an apostrophe add another apostrophe...

so a string like `it's` should be inserted as `it''s`

You may also need to escape quotation marks. The way to do this is to use a backslash as an escape charater...

like so... `'and he said\"escape all those quotes\"'`

You should also beware of SQL injections... depending on the type of programming language you are using there exist different functions that can help clean out any malicious code.

[C# tutorial on SQL Injections for example](http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Avoiding_SQL_Injection)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, did you have some literature on insight on my second question by chance?

Comment: @CODe I've made an amendment to my post, as per your request.

Comment: Thanks! Per your link, how do I modify their "proper way to build an ad hoc SQL query" with an update/where command instead of an insert command?

Answer (score 1):

You should never concatenate strings to build SQL queries for SQLite - or for any other SQL DB if possible. It makes your code fragile and opens up potential entry points for injection attacks.

The proper way to do it is to use [hosted parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). This approach removes the need for cumbersome string filtering. I am not sure how to do that in C# for SQLite but any decent language binding for SQLite should allow you to use hosted parameters.