# SQL logic error or missing database no such function: NVARCHAR in c#.net using sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
 public DataTable Get_VISITER_MST_BY_ID(string id)
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     using (SQLiteConnection con = DBCONNECTION.Connection())
     {
         con.Open();
         using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT VISITER_ID, VISITER_IMAGE, VISITER_INTIME, VISITER_SCANTIME, VISITER_STATUS, VISITER_CANCELTIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),VISITER_SCANTIME, 100) AS TIME FROM         VISITER_MST WHERE     (VISITER_ID = '" + id + "'" + ")", con))
         {
             da.Fill(ds);
         }
     }
     return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQLite. There is no datatype `NVARCHAR`, Your current syntax is valid for SQL Server. In SQLite there is only `text`  datatype (for string) which is Unicode.  See more about [SQLite Data 
Types.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Your current query has `NVARCHAR(100)` which is interpretted as a method and hence the exception.

`DATETIME` datatype in SQLite is stored as `Numeric`. You may look at [Date and Time functions in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the Time Part from your field.

Also consider using Parameters for your query instead of string concatenation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

SqlLite have not NVARCHAR it only allow text

Comment: so what we taken for datetime in sqlite?

Comment: SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.[Reference Link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: so i only change in datetime insted of nvarchar in this query??then this problem will solve or not?

Comment: As i told my earlier comment there is no specific datetime like SQL.In your quey please use text