# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#

Tags: c#, database, object

i can get record from database and take its into objects

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedFishes.Length; i++)
{
    string stm = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE name='" + selectedFishes[i] + "'";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, conn);
    SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        fish[i] = new fish(rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetDouble(1), rdr.GetDouble(2), rdr.GetDouble(3), rdr.GetDouble(4));
        Console.WriteLine(fish[i].name + " " + fish[i].value1 + " " + fish[i].value2 + " " + fish[i].value3 + " " + fish[i].value4);//it can be displayed into console
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(selectedFishes.Length.ToString()+" "+fish.Length.ToString());//results are same if the value >5 cant be displayed
for (int i = 0; i < fish.Length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(fish[i].name + " " + fish[i].value1 + " " + fish[i].value2 + " " + fish[i].value3 + " " + fish[i].value4);

}
```

why cant be displayed?
the error is"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
thanks before

Comment: On which line is the error occuring?

Comment: second console.writeline

Comment: are you getting the correct o/p on Message box ?

Comment: Just debug and check the value of 'fish[i]' for null

Comment: Apart of *on which line is the error occuring*, the next question is *on which iteration number occurs the error?*

Comment: Irrelevant, but consider using the `Parameters` property of your `SQLiteCommand` instead of simply concatenating a `string`. It will make this part of your code a little safer against malicious input.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Not just a *little* safer - much, **much** safer.

Comment: TheodorosChatzigiannakis:give me an example please

Comment: @NadzarBagus See Björn's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp

Comment: thanks all, for your answer, i will debug myself..
maybe in the checkboxes for selectedfish there is a error...
my checkboxes are devided into 5 columns,and if i select all 3nd and 5th columns, the error occurs

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking a wild guess and say that `selectedFishes.Length` is probably not equal to `fish.Length`. To be precise the former is most likely less than the latter.

Which means you only create objects for indices 0 to `selectedFishes.Length-1` and then try to access index `selectedFishes.Length` which is still `null` and cause that exception.

To fix this you can change the upper bound of the second for loop or do a null check inside it.

Edit: and do you really want that while loop inside the first for loop? `i` doesn't change inside the while loop so you keep adding `fish` objects into the same array index.

Comment: Yes, this matches the described symptoms. I would say that `selectedFishes.Length < fish.Length` rather than just `selectedFishes.Length != fish.Length`

Comment: i've tried to change fish.lenght in to selectedfishes.lenght, but the result is same

Answer (score 1):

I'd say always in NullReferenceException try to ToString() each object that you expect to have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoit to the second console writeline by pressing f9. Press f5. Let your program hit the breakpoint. Check ifname or value1-4 is null. Add code to handle null values.

Comment: If you cannot reach the second console writeline where you told us the error occurs then then there must be something wrong earlier. Add abreakpoint some lines above and step through the code investigating the contents of your objects. You should read some introduction about debugging in visual studio.  You will need debugging with a propability of 100%.