# SQLite simple insert query

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite as my storage. I've added reference dll using nuget and using statement as well.

I have

```
private void SetConnection()
{
    sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
        ("Data Source=c:\\Dev\\MYApp.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
}

private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();
    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql_con.Close(); 
}
```

and I'm sending query txt like this

```
public void Create(Book book)
{
    string txtSqlQuery  = "INSERT INTO Book (Id, Title, Language, PublicationDate, Publisher, Edition, OfficialUrl, Description, EBookFormat) ";
    txtSqlQuery += string.Format("VALUES (@{0},@{1},@{2},@{3},@{4},@{5},@{6},@{7},{8})", 
                book.Id, book.Title, book.Language, book.PublicationDate, book.Publisher, book.Edition, book.OfficialUrl, book.Description, book.EBookFormat);
    try
    {
        ExecuteQuery(txtSqlQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception ex )
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

My db is correctly created and passed book instance with valid data is ok. But exception is thrown always on executing query on this line of code:

```
sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I obviously doing something wrong here but I cannot see.

Update: thrown exception message is

> SQL logic error or missing database
>
> unrecognized token: "22cf"

where this `22cf` is part of passed `book.Id` guid string.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: @Alireza updated questio

Comment: I noticed that you are not using formal parameters to your SQL command. This is not very much advisable, because you will have to worry about presenting data into a SQL statement (i.e formatting dates, decimal separators, etc...).

Comment: @ user2783193 can you please tell how the argument `book` looks? Is the argument to `Create` method a list?

Answer (score 57):

[Don't EVER insert your data in your statement!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Use prepared statements and bind parameters:

```
public void Create(Book book) {
    SQLiteCommand insertSQL = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Book (Id, Title, Language, PublicationDate, Publisher, Edition, OfficialUrl, Description, EBookFormat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", sql_con);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Id);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Title);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Language);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.PublicationDate);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Publisher);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Edition);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.OfficialUrl);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.Description);
    insertSQL.Parameters.Add(book.EBookFormat);
    try {
        insertSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This example does not work if parameters are not string type.

Comment: That's not correct: [SqlParameterCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136439.aspx) accepts Object values. Of course, implementations will convert .NET types to appropriate database types. SQLite implementation accepts string types but also numeric types, null, ...

Comment: This is SQLiteParameterCollection.Add(), but you are right -- it does accept Object. I must have made some mistake when I was testing. In any case, IntelliSense is not showing that version of Add() once you type the opening parenthesis (it shows it only when you type . before Add).

Comment: How can I do nested or recursive additions if the object is complex?

Comment: This does not seem to be valid. You get a casting error complaining that your object is not of type `SQLiteParameter`.

Comment: Silly question, a few years too late, but if you wanted to add multiple records in one `INSERT` while using prepared statements, how would you do that? This seems to be hardcoded to one `INSERT` at a time, even though you can insert multiple rows in one `INSERT` statement

Comment: Hi JPMC, standard (and probably faster) way of doing this is using transactions: create a prepared statement once like above, start with `BEGIN`, execute same prepared statement many times, using different parameters at will, and finally finish with `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Update most recent version using Dapper (Dapper.2.0.90) and SQLite (System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.114.2)

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using Dapper;
```

> connection string (DB name - 'Store.db')

`connectionString="Data Source=.\Store.db;Version=3;"`

> Person save method in my application

```
public static void SavePerson(PersonModel person)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        cnn.Execute("insert into Person (FirstName, LastName) values (@FirstName, @LastName)", new { person.FirstName, person.LastName} );
    }
}
```

> person model

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ FirstName } { LastName }";
        }
    }
}
```

This answer includes the code methods I used and use in my applications.

Answer (score -2):

**To insert the records into the SqliteDB:**

```cs
using System.Data.SQLite;

private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string connection = @"Data Source=C:\Folder\SampleDB.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
    string stringQuery ="INSERT INTO _StudyInfo"+"(Param,Val)"+"Values('Name','" + snbox.Text + "')";//insert the studyinfo into Db
    sqlite_conn.Open();//Open the SqliteConnection
    var SqliteCmd = new SQLiteCommand();//Initialize the SqliteCommand
    SqliteCmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();//Create the SqliteCommand
    SqliteCmd.CommandText = stringQuery;//Assigning the query to CommandText
    SqliteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Execute the SqliteCommand
    sqlite_conn.Close();//Close the SqliteConnection
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You should use (') when sending string into INSERT statement
VALUES (@{0},'@{1}','@{2}','@{3}','@{4}','@{5}','@{6}','@{7}',{8})
you should also catch SQLExeprion

Comment: Great answer, I would probably use named params tho as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp  Why? because in some of my sql statement you might be using the same parameter a few different times.