# Visual Basic 2015 SQLite Update Query not working

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I used **NuGet Package Manage**r to install SQLite package in my Visual Basic 2015 Project so that i can use it in my application. The problem i am facing is that i have a sub in my application whose code is indicated below that i am using to update a table in SQLite but it does not update the values.

**AddErrors** is another sub that adds the errors that are captured by the try catch to the same SQLite database but different table and works fine. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong.

I have tried both the commented and the uncommitted code with both not updating the database and not throwing any errors.

```
Public Sub PostedLink(ByVal id As String, ByVal link As String)
    Dim query As String = "UPDATE Table SET torf = 1 , link = '" & link & "' WHERE id = '" & id & "';"
    Dim affectedRows As Integer = 0
    Try
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(con)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 20
                cmd.CommandText = query
                'Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader
                'dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        AddErrors("Updating table", ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The table i am trying to update has the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE Table
(
id VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
text VARCHAR(100),
link VARCHAR(254) DEFAULT "",
torf BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: You should be using a parameterized query, currently you are vulnerable to SQL Injection, and a `'` character in your varibles will break things. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp

Comment: If there is no exception and the update does not occur then most likely there WHERE clause matches no rows. (Disable exception catching to be 100% sure)

Comment: Your table is not named `Table`, it is `PostsList`. You have a typo.

Comment: And a bug in AddErrors() if the SqliteException that would raise is ignored.

Comment: I have changed the table names and variables for the question. The table name was not the problem. I changed the code as suggested by Alex and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I changed the code to use parameterized query as follows and it worked flawlessly.

```
Public Sub PostedLink(ByVal id As String, ByVal link As String)
    Dim query As String = "UPDATE Table SET torf = 1, link = @link WHERE id = @id;"
    Dim affectedRows As Integer = 0
    Try
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(con)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 20
                cmd.CommandText = query
                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add(New SQLiteParameter("@link", link))
                    .Add(New SQLiteParameter("@id", id))
                End With
                'Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader
                'dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        AddErrors("Updating table", ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```