# How to write variable DateTime value in SQLite database through C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I'm very new to `C#` and `SQLite` database and have some variables which to be stored in SQLite database along with `TimeStamp`.
Here is my code:

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    var sql = string.Format("insert into Table (Timestamp) values ({0})", now);
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I'm getting error. I guess, SQLite doesn't support `DateTime`. I tried converting `DateTime now` to `string` but it still doesn't work.

```
    DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now;
    var now = now1.ToString("hh.mm.ss.fff");
    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    var sql = string.Format("insert into Table (Timestamp) values ({0})", now);
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong. Use Parametrized queries and you'll avoid this kind of problems and many more. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/809246/579895) for an example

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters to avoid SQL injection:

```
var sql = string.Format("insert into Table (Timestamp) values (@now)", now);
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now",now);
```

Comment: @Polyfun although i agree that you should always be using parameters, I think editing other's answer is not the way to go. I'd rather make a comment suggesting him to change it

Comment: I'm getting following error because of the line 
`command.Parameters.Add("@now", now);`

CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.DbType'

Comment: @Keshav, Edited, try with AddWithValue

Comment: @apomene Yes, it worked. Could you tell me the difference as well?

Comment: Add also expects the sql DBType provided as an argument