# Save byte array to SQLite database c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

please I can not solve it, some ideas? I see in DB only "System.Byte []" but no values from array.
Thank you.

[image: First image here]
[image: Second image]

Comment: Please use [bind parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` on a `byte[]` yields

> `System.Byte[]`

---

But assuming that your `byte[]` contains a (UTF8 formatted) string, you could use

```
byte[] array= ...;
string myString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);
```

instead.