# Problem importing data in SQLite C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Make a meteorological application that reads data from files.
I have a problem importing the data.

I tried importing it, but I came across an error:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error 11 values for 12
>   columns'

```
private SQLiteConnection Connection;

SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("meteodb.sqlite");

Connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=meteodb.sqlite;Version=3;");

Connection.Open();

string createTable = ("CREATE TABLE meteodata (Station INT(5) NOT NULL, Dat datetime NOT NULL, Temp FLOAT(7, 1), Hum FLOAT(7, 1), Press FLOAT(7, 1), windSpeed FLOAT(7, 1), windDirection FLOAT(7, 1), Rain FLOAT(7, 1), rainIntensity FLOAT(7, 1), notDraw FLOAT(7, 1), notDraw1 FLOAT(7, 1), sunRad FLOAT(7, 1), PRIMARY KEY(Station, Dat));");

SQLiteCommand createHydDnev = new SQLiteCommand(createTable, Connection);
createHydDnev.ExecuteNonQuery();

SQLiteCommand sqlComm;
sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("begin", Connection);
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();           

string insertData = ("INSERT INTO meteodata (Station, Dat, Temp, Hum, Press, windSpeed, windDirection, Rain, rainIntensity, notDraw, notDraw1, sunRad) " +
                    "values (" + item.id + ",'" + item.date + "'," + item.temperature + ",'" + item.hum + ",'" + item.presure + "," + item.windSpeed + "," + item.windDirect + "," + item.rain + "," + item.rainIntensity + "," + item.notDraw + "," +  item.notDraw1 + "," + item.sunRadiation + ");");

SQLiteCommand fillData = new SQLiteCommand(insertData, Connection);
fillData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I expect to fill the table, but I receive the above error.

Comment: Please use parameters instead of concatenating strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp

Comment: The problem occurs most probably from the insert statement 'item.date'. I think if you use parameters as @mm8 suggested you can insert correctly into your table

Comment: there is a typo ... use parameters to avoid them(typos) and sql injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use parameters instead of concatenating strings:

```
const string InsertData = "INSERT INTO meteodata (Station, Dat, Temp, Hum, Press, windSpeed, windDirection, Rain, rainIntensity, notDraw, notDraw1, sunRad) " +
    "values (@Station, @Dat, @Temp, @Hum, @Press, @windSpeed, @windDirection, @Rain, @rainIntensity, @notDraw, @notDraw1, @sunRad)";

SQLiteCommand fillData = new SQLiteCommand(insertData, Connection);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", item.id);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dat", item.date);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temp", item.temperature);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hum", item.hum);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Press", item.presure);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@windSpeed", item.windSpeed);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@windDirection", item.windDirect);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rain", item.rain);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rainIntensity", item.rainIntensity);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notDraw", item.notDraw);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notDraw1", item.notDraw1);
fillData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sunRad", item.sunRadiation);
fillData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'constraint failed

UNIQUE constraint failed: meteodata.Station, meteodata.Dat'

With this code I have this error ?

Comment: Then your original issue has been solved beause the `INSERT` statement is executed. Apparently you have a `UNIQUE` constraint set up in your database that prevents your from adding duplictate values in the `Stat` and `Dat` columns.

Comment: I try with INSERT or IGNORE querry and then program work properly I think... :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem in your code:

`...",'" + item.hum + ",'"...` - note the misplaced single quotes, around `item.hum`.

The other parameters-based answer is indeed better.