# Eliminating an option from a ComboBox (2), based on the input of the first ComboBox (1) c#

Tags: c#, sql, forms, sqlite, combobox

I am creating an airline booking system and I have 2 combo boxes. The first is for Departure City and the second is for Arrival City. I want to be able to eliminate the choice in the first combo box from the second, as I don't want the same city to be able to be submitted as both the departure and arrival city. I am querying the city names from a database.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string connectionString = @"Base Schema Name=cyanair;data source=C:\Users\Client 0819\source\repos\Cyanair\cyanair.db";

        //Departure ComboBox
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CyanairAirports";

            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboDeparture.DataSource = dt;
            comboDeparture.ValueMember = "Descriptions";
            comboDeparture.DisplayMember = "Descriptions";



            conn.Close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //Arrival ComboBox
    private void comboDeparture_DisplayMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Base Schema Name=cyanair;data source=C:\Users\Client 0819\source\repos\Cyanair\cyanair.db";
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

        **String city = comboDeparture.DisplayMember;**

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();


            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CyanairAirports WHERE Descriptions IS NOT '" + comboDeparture.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
            richTextBox1.Text = "SELECT * FROM CyanairAirports WHERE Descriptions IS NOT '" + comboDeparture.SelectedValue + "'";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboArrival.DataSource = dt;
            comboArrival.ValueMember = "Descriptions";
            comboArrival.DisplayMember = "Descriptions";


            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: So, what's the question? Is there something about the code you've posted that isn't working? If so, what isn't working? Is an exception being thrown? `comboArrival` isn't populated? `comboArrival` doesn't filter?

Comment: used if condition and comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.SelectedIndex; then true don't submit application

Comment: Just use a filter on the datasource rather than running a new query everytime.  And never, ever concat data into a string for a query

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson comboArrival IS being populated, but it doesn't filter the result. If for example 'London' is chosen in comboDeparture I would like for London to not appear as an option in comboArrival. Both comboBoxes are using the same table of locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're handling the [`DisplayMemberChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymemberchanged) event on `comboDeparture`, and trying to update the values of `comboArrival` in that handler. However, `DisplayMemberChanged` only triggers when the [`DisplayMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember) property changes.

`DisplayMember` only tells the control which property to display on a data bound control. It isn't tied to the index or value selected in the `ComboBox`. So, the only time the code to populate `comboArrival` runs is in the constructor when you set `comboDepartarture.DisplayMember`. Instead, handle either [`ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged) or [`ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged) and set the items of `comboArrival`.

A few other important things to note about your code.

First, you should use a parameterized query when running Sql Statements, rather than concatenating strings. Concatenating strings as you're doing opens you up to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'm not familiar with SqlLite and can't provide you with an example of how to modify your code, but perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp) can help.

Second, you don't need to re-run the query every time you change the selected value in `comboDeparture`. Just add `comboArrival`'s data source as a field on the `Form` and you can filter it. For example...

```
public partial class main : Form
{
   // Your constructors...

   private void comboDepartures_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (_arrivalsDataSource == null)
      {
          _arrivalsDataSource = new System.Data.DataTable();
          // Load _arrivalsDataSource from the database, basically how you're doing it now.
          comboArrival.DataSource = _arrivalsDataSource.DefaultView;
          comboArrival.DisplayMember = "Descriptions"
          comboArribal.ValueMember = "Descriptions"
      }
      if (comboDeparture.SelectedIndex == -1)
      {
          _arrivalsDataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = null; // Clear the filter.
      }
      else
      {
          // Set the filter.
          _arrivalsDataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Description <> '{comboDeparture.SelectedValue}'";
      }
   }

   private System.Data.DataTable _arrivalsDataSource = null;
}
```