# How to retrieve data from database using WHERE BETWEEN for variables in Sqlite c#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have an Sqlite row `createDate` in messages table. I want to retrieve all records from messages where `createDate` is between `startDate` and `endDate` local variables in method.

Any suggestion, how to write query for `string stm`? Or any other way how to do it

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDate = endDate.AddDays(-7);

using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
{
    con.Open();

    string stm = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE createDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";

    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= rdr.FieldCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = rdr.GetValue(j).ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You aren't binding `@startDate` and `@endDate` in the statement?

Comment: @AKX yes, I want to compare createDate row from DB with local variables startDate and endDate, but don't know how to correctly write query

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the parameters like this ([syntax borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809275/51685)):

```
string stm = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE createDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";

using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate));
   // ...
```

Comment: but there is no startDate and endDate in DB, how it could be useful?

Comment: The `@startDate` and `@endDate` parameter placeholders in your statement are replaced with the values of those local variables you have.

Answer (score 0):

SQLLite requires dates to be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Since the data in your database and the string in your query isn't in that format, it is probably treating your "dates" as strings.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2021-02-11" AND "2021-08-11";
```