# SQLiteConnection parameterized query c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to find a solution to this but could find no help anywhere.
I have a SqliteConnection object and I to this I m using the query selector to pass a parameterized query but could not find any help on that.

```
private SqliteConnection dbConn;
var users = dbConn.Query<Users>($"SELECT * FROM {nameof(Users)} WHERE {nameof(Users.Id)} = '{userID}'").FirstOrDefault();
```

Here userID is the input variable.How to make this parameterized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding parameters in SQLite with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809246/adding-parameters-in-sqlite-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Unfortunately No, I did see that post but its adding parameters to the command object, I need to modify the query selector on the connection object.

Comment: Are you using `SqliteConnection` from a specific library?  Does that vendor provide documentation?

Comment: The connection object does not have a native "query selector" out of the box. Are you using Dapper? Or EF?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the classes from **sqlite-net-pcl**:

You can use question marks as place holders for values and then pass the actual values as additional parameters:

```
var user = dbConn.Query<Users>($"SELECT * FROM {nameof(Users)} " +
    $"WHERE {nameof(Users.Id)} = ? " +
    $"OR {nameof(Users.Id)} = ?", userID, alternativeUserID)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The documentation says:

> Creates a SQLiteCommand given the command text (SQL) with arguments. Place a '?' in the command text for each of the arguments and then executes that command. It returns each row of the result using the mapping automatically generated for the given type.

---

You can also use [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) to automatically generate an sql query from C# code:

```
var user = dbConn.Table<Users>().Where(row => row.Id == userID || row.Id == alternativeUserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Look at the source code for more details:
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize table and column names; you probably need to hard-code that part. Separately, when you parameterize the value, **don't include the quote marks**.

While I'm here, thanks to connection pooling it's also poor practice to try to re-use the same connection object, so instead of `private SqliteConnection dbConn;` it should be more like `private string sqliteConnectionString = "...";`

So assuming the query method will do automatic parameterization of the interpolation via FormattableString, we end up with this:

```
private string sqliteConnectionString = "...";

using var conn = new SqliteConnection(sqliteConnectionString);
var users = conn.Query<Users>($"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = {userID}").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If this is about sqlite-net-pcl, the Query method does not support FormattableString, but it supports using question marks and additional value parameters. See my answer.